# Mongoose validation from custom schema

Tags: validation, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a schema like this:

```
let schema1 = new Schema({
    code: String,
    translation: {}
});
```

and anoter schema like this:

```
let schema2 = new Schema({
    content: String
});
```

and for exemple, I want a validation on schema1.translation.en based on schema2.

Because isn't possible to have dynamic key on object(according to my searches).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: currently not possible

Comment: I would have tried with "this.schema = schema2" but not work :D

Comment: You can set reference to `schema1`... which is quite simple

Comment: No because can't set dynamic keys in object.

Comment: then it is not possible... even if it is possible then Neil would have answered till...